# Fire OnChange and OnClick events of TreeView, but not both

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I am using a TreeView in Delphi whereby I use its `OnChange` event to add the selected item to a ComboBox.

But the big problem is that the `OnChange` event does not work when you click on the selected item in the TreeView. It only works when I click on an item that is not selected.

To resolve this issue I also use the `OnClick` event. But then the problem becomes that both events are fired for an unselected item:

```
procedure Test;
begin
  ShowMessage('submit');
end;

procedure TForm1.TreeView1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Test;
end;

procedure TForm1.TreeView1Change(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
begin
  Test;
end;
```

It runs the ShowMessage two times. How do I check if there was a previous event, or if an event is currently running?

Something similar to jQuery:

```
$ ("#foo") .bind ("Change click", function () {
   $ (This) .toggleClass ("entered");
});
```

Comment: Please post code that actually performs the way that you describe. It's true that `Test` is called twice, but not anymore since you added the `ShowMessage('submit')`, because that exits the TreeView (defocuses).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a way too obvious solution, but did you try to ... only use the `OnClick` event?

---

But to answer your question, how to prevent the second event from firing:

A typical solution would be to store the previous selected index in a variable, and check that variable:

```
procedure TForm1.TreeView1Change(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
begin
  Test;
end;

procedure TForm1.TreeView1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if TreeView1.Selected.Index = FPrevTreeViewIndex then
    Test;
  FPrevTreeViewIndex := TreeView1.Selected.Index;
end;
```